# Can we Add (RFID) Devices With Asp.net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, devise

I make a apllication (File Tracking System ) on Windows which is based on (Aliean Reader)
which is Working Fine the purpose of this Application is to locating the File (Each File have a tag) with the help of reader we can easily Identify the File is in the Room or now i want to make this Application on Web so i m Confuse How Can we use Reader with Web Application one of My colleague  Say me that we can use it through Window Service ..

how can we manage all (Reader,Window Service , Web Application)

Thanks And Regard

Shashank

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a Service for this as the actually physical reader will be sitting on the users local pc.

I would suggest you look at using Silverlight with elevated out of browser functionality. This will allow the silverlight application to access local resources like coms and ports.
If you want to use asp.NET you will need to use ActiveX controls in order to get data of the reader directly. Well thats what I had to do, and very messy, rather go for the Silverlight method.